# how to write a class function with type stack

Tags: c++, function, class, stack, prototype

I have nodes.h which defines CNode as such

```
  struct CNode
   {
      int data;
      CNode* link;
   };
```

Then, I have a separate header called queue.h with this class definition with an interesting function:

```
Class queue
{ 
public:
 .... //other functions
 CNode* front();
... //private members
};
```

My job is to write the implementation (queue.cpp) of queue.h.
Thus, my question is: how would I write the prototype for this in the implementation file?

I have already tried these 2 with no success:

```
queue::CNode* front()
{}

queue::queue CNode*::front()
{}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The syntax is as usual: return value, name, parameters. So `CNode* queue::front()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
CNode* queue::front()
```

assuming `CNode` is defined outside `queue`.

Without `queue::` you would be declaring a completely different global function.